# How to rename '/posts/' default posts location in Astro?

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I'm greping source code for my project
and i seems '/posts/' default is hardcoded:

`` src/components/Search.tsx:115:              href={`/posts/${item.slug}/`} ``

I docs it says that

```
{
  base: '/docs'
}
```

should be used, but when I add it to astro.config.ts nothing changes.

I'm using https://github.com/satnaing/astro-paper so could it be the feature of the template I'm using?

I want to have urls like:

```
mysite.example/author1/article1
mysite.example/author1/article2
...
mysite.example/author2/article1
```

And fighting with the collections, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you mentioned is coming from [Search.tsx in the astro-paper](https://github.com/satnaing/astro-paper/blob/main/src/components/Search.tsx#L115) template. You can just edit it from `/posts/` to `/author/1` and rename the [`/posts/` directory](https://github.com/satnaing/astro-paper/tree/main/src/pages/posts) to `/author/`.

Read the [astro docs on routing](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/routing/) to learn how this works in detail.